# C: Concatenate a word and a number to single identifier runtime

Tags: c, concatenation, identifier

I want to concatenate one word and one number to a single identifier like using the ## preprocessor operator, and use this to index an array. However, it has to happen at runtime. Ideally, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RUNTIME_CONCAT(a,b) //Insert concatenating operation here

int main(){
    int foo1[2][1] = {{2}, {5}};
    int foo2[2][1] = {{6}, {9}};

    /*
    By some means acquire number a here
    */

    int* print_val = RUNTIME_CONCAT(foo, a)[1];

    printf("Value: %d\n", *print_val);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The preprocessor, by definition, runs at preprocessing time, which is one of the first stages of compilation.  You cannot use preprocessor directives at runtime.

Comment: Why not add a 3rd dimension to your arrays, so `foo1` and `foo2` would become `foo[0]` and `foo[1]`?

Comment: Oh you want to construct `foo1` or `foo2` at runtime and access that array? That is not possible, compiled code has no notion of variable names, you will need to architect another way. A pointer to the appropriate `foo` is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following shows how to concatenate two item together at runtime

```
char myword[] = "the word";
int  mynumber = 27;
char *myarray = malloc( 100 );  //note 100 is much larger than needed

sprintf( &myarray[ strlen(myarray) ], "%s%d", myword, mynumber );
```

after the above is executed, myarray[] will contain:

```
"the word27"
```

Answer (score 1):

If yu want to use macro:

```
typedef int (*arr21)[2][1];

#define RT(arr, x)  (int *)(((arr21 []){&arr ## 1, &arr ## 2})[x])
```

`typedef` is only for the sake of simplicity - otherwise the syntax of compound literal would be quite hard to read.

```
#define RT(arr, x)  (int *)(((arr21 []){&arr ## 1, &arr ## 2})[x])

int main(void){
    int foo1[2][1] = {{2}, {5}};
    int foo2[2][1] = {{6}, {9}};

    volatile int a = 1;

    int* print_val = RT(foo, a);
    printf("Value: %d\n", *print_val);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rjWMrzda9

Answer (score 1):

I propose a little bit of ugly code, but I think it is what you're looking for. Comments after the code.

```
/* so.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo1[2][1] = {{2}, {5}};
int foo2[2][3] = {{6, 3, 1}, {9, 7, 5}};

struct array_t {
    char *name;
    void *ptr;

    /* int foo[m][n] */
    size_t m, n;
};

struct array_t array[] = {
#define __set(v)    {# v, v, \
    sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]), \
    sizeof(v[0]) / sizeof(v[0][0])}
    __set(foo1),
    __set(foo2),
#undef __set
};

void *getarray(char *base, int idx)
{
    char name[100];
    snprintf(name, 100, "%s%d", base, idx);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(struct array_t); i++)
        if(!strcmp(array[i].name, name))
            return &array[i];
    return NULL;
}

int val(struct array_t *array, int m, int n)
{
    int *p = array->ptr;
    return p[m * array->n + n];
}

void print_array(struct array_t *array)
{
    printf("Array: %s[%zu][%zu]\n\n", array->name, array->m, array->n);

    for(int m = 0; m < array->m; m++)
        for(int n = 0; n < array->n; n++)
            printf("%s[%d][%d] = %d\n",
                array->name, m, n, val(array, m, n));

    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct array_t *p1, *p2;

    p1 = getarray("foo", 1);
    p2 = getarray("foo", 2);

    print_array(p1);
    print_array(p2);

    printf("foo2[1][2]: %d\n", val(p2, 1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

1. I defined two arrays of different sizes to try and make something more generic.
2. We define a structured called `array_t` which holds information about our arrays.
3. We initialize our structure with the arrays. This is the first bit of preprocessing ugliness.
4. `__set(v)` depends on `static` arrays to function (ie. it won't work with `malloc` arrays). `# v` converts the name of the variable to a string.
5. The next interesting bit is `sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0])` which calculates the `m` dimention of the array by dividing the total size of the array by the row size.
6. `sizeof(v[0]) / sizeof(v[0][0])` divides the total row size by the size of the type.
7. `getarray` is where the lookup happens. You can get a name and an index, then `snprintf` will create a string for you and loop up in our global table `array`.
8. `val` is a wrapper to give you the element at a given index of a 2D array.
9. `print_array`... well, prints the array.